# Cannot copy a byte from a VMDK file stream with DiscUtils C# library

Tags: c#

I Use .NET DiscUtils to access a VMDK disc in C#. I can access files and get informations about them, but when I try to use Streams to copy them, I get:

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Attempt to move beyond end of stream`

When debugging, I see that the exception is fired from [SubStream.cs at line 99](https://github.com/perpetual-motion/discutils/blob/master/src/SubStream.cs) when setting the position cursor in the Stream.

I cannot understand why this is fired... here is my code :

```
using DiscUtils;
using DiscUtils.Fat;
using DiscUtils.Vmdk;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DebugDiscUtils
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Me\VirtualBox VMs\ECS\myECSDisk-disk2.vmdk";
            VirtualDisk disk = new DiscUtils.Vmdk.Disk(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite), Ownership.None);
            FatFileSystem fs2 = new FatFileSystem(disk.Partitions[0].Open());
            Stream s = fs2.OpenFile(fs2.GetFiles(fs2.Root.Name)[0], FileMode.Open);
            Console.WriteLine("L: " + s.Length);
            try
            {
                int val = s.ReadByte(); //******The Exception is fired HERE********//
                int cpt  = 1;
                while (val != -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Byte " + cpt + ": " + val);
                    val = s.ReadByte();
                    cpt++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is the stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Attempt to move beyond end of stream
Parameter name: value

   at DiscUtils.SubStream.set_Position(Int64 value) in c:\Data\Dev\C#\discutils_
f0bb9c34a81e\src\SubStream.cs:line 99

   at DiscUtils.Fat.ClusterReader.ReadCluster(UInt32 cluster, Byte[] buffer, Int
32 offset) in c:\Data\Dev\C#\discutils_f0bb9c34a81e\src\Fat\ClusterReader.cs:lin
e 66

   at DiscUtils.Fat.ClusterStream.TryLoadClusterByPosition(Int64 pos) in c:\Data
\Dev\C#\discutils_f0bb9c34a81e\src\Fat\ClusterStream.cs:line 396

   at DiscUtils.Fat.ClusterStream.TryLoadCurrentCluster() in c:\Data\Dev\C#\disc
utils_f0bb9c34a81e\src\Fat\ClusterStream.cs:line 382

   at DiscUtils.Fat.ClusterStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 in c:\Data\Dev\C#\discutils_f0bb9c34a81e\src\Fat\ClusterStream.cs:line 143

   at DiscUtils.Fat.FatFileStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
 in c:\Data\Dev\C#\discutils_f0bb9c34a81e\src\Fat\FatFileStream.cs:line 125

   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()

   at DebugDiscUtils.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Data\Dev\C#\discutils_f0b
b9c34a81e\DebugDiscUtils\Program.cs:line 26
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace.

Comment: And what length is shown, just before the `try` block? (This sounds like it's basically going to be a bug in a library which hasn't been updated for a long time...)

Comment: It shows 2, which is OK because it is a text file with 2 chararacters. It may be a bug yes...